# Are the angels known to public?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

We know that SEELE leaked the information about the Second Impact as a "meteor impact" into the public to cover up the contact experiment.

Since the angels are huge entities and surely visible from afar, is the public informed about what the angels truly are?

Comment: I thought the answer was an obvious "yes" (for a definition of "what the angels truly are" that doesn't extend much further than "giant monsters"), but when I skimmed episode 3 for clear evidence, I found some contradictory implications, and in any case they would only apply clearly to the civilian population of Shin Tokyo-3 at most. Looking forward to seeing someone cobble together something more coherent.